# BrowserSync and Jade auto reload

Tags: pug, gulp, browser-sync

I'm having some issues getting browsersync to play nice with my jade setup.

I have split out my jade files into lots of smaller partials to be included in each of my master templates.

The folder structure is as follows.

```
jade
   source
      _includes
         _header.jade
         _footer.jade
      template.jade
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
  var YOUR_LOCALS = {

  };

  gulp.src(config.src)
    .pipe(changed(config.dest, {extension: '.html'}))
    .pipe(jade({
      locals: YOUR_LOCALS,
      pretty: true,
      basedir: config.basedir
    }))

    .on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync(
    server: {
        baseDir: "./"
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function() {
    gulp.watch(config.jade.watch, ['jade']);
});

nb. all of my paths are defined in a big ole' config object
```

My gulp watcher is looking at all of the jade files ('jade/source/**/*.jade')

The setup works perfectly well when i make a change to my template.jade file.  However, if I make an edit to one of my partials the task is not run.

This is because of `.pipe(changed('./', {extension: '.html'}))`

If I remove this line, all of the jade files will compile and the browser will reload a number of times before the change has been rendered in the browser (i quite often have to manually refresh the page to see the changes).

I feel like i need to use `.pipe(changed('./', {extension: '.html'}))` in some form to stop ALL of the templates from being process, but in away which captures the changes made in partial templates.

Any ideas? 
Thanks
Dave

Comment: Could you include the part where you set up browser-sync?

Comment: Thanks for your reply... If I set stream: false, I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined (plus a few dozen lines of node errors). Odd! // UDPATE... I'll add that now.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% this will solve your problem but if you pass browserSync.reload as a second task when a jade file changes you should always see a refresh:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function() {
    gulp.watch(config.jade.watch, ['jade', browserSync.reload]);
});
```

Note: this will cause an actual refresh and doesn't use streams.

Comment: Thanks, This working for me solve the problem where browserSync reload before `pug` complete and I have to manually refresh page. This problem starts when I removed `.pipe(changed('dist', {extension: '.html'}))` as per question asked. and browser reload may times. thanks